# Using SUMIF/SUMIFS for a Column with both Numbers and Strings

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I'm making somewhat of a bill tracker of my own in Google Sheets. This is snippet so far what I have.

Google Sheet Example Image
[image: Google Sheet Example Image]

What I want to accomplish is on cell `K2`, you can see that if the cell to the right of the K column is not checked `(aka it = FALSE)`, then it adds it to the total where I can see what the total amount I still need to keep in order to pay my bills.

Below is the formula being used for `K2`

```
=SUMIF(L5:L,FALSE,K5:K)
```

Now, I do have a couple of different accounts myself, so it would be useful to know which bills are taken out of what account, to get a breakdown of that too.

My problem is, I can't figure out a good way to go about this. Maybe SUMIFS is not the way to go for that. The following formula is what I tried.

```
=SUMIFS(K5:K, L5:L, FALSE, K5:K, "CHK 1")
```

Although this just returns a "$0.00" for me. I figure it's because when it checks cell K8 (as an example), it checks `L8` if it is FALSE, which it is, but then it also tries to check the same `K8` to see if it is equal to the string "CHK 1", but it obviously would never be correct since that is the cell with the number value I want to add.

Is there a way to make the criteria check the cell 2 spots below? I tried using...

```
=SUMIFS(K5:K, L5:L, FALSE, K5:K, INDIRECT(R2C0, FALSE)&"=CHK 1")
```

But this results in a formula parse error. I've been looking around at any other formulas that may work but I haven't found anything yet. Anyone able to help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=SUMIFS(K5:K100, L5:L100, FALSE, K7:K102, "CHK 1")
```